# Build Error on Android using Capacitor on Gradle

Tags: android, gradle, ionic3, capacitor

We have developed Mobile App via Capacitor, Currently when we build via DevOps it gives error as,

```
> Configure project :app
Project app at :app is either no Android app project or build version has not been set to override. Skipping...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script '/Users/runner/work/1/s/android/app/capacitor.build.gradle' line: 10

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating script.
> Could not read script '/Users/runner/work/1/s/android/capacitor-cordova-android-plugins/cordova.variables.gradle' as it does not exist.
```

Thank in Advance.

Comment: I am missing a minimal effort on your side. Have you read the error message? there are mentioned 2 files. What text is on line 10 of the .gradle file? Is the other file not existent on the given path. Also i am reading cordova(not sure what it is), have you installed/downloaded it correctly?

Answer (score 4):

You need to run `npx cap sync` in your DevOps server, after the `npm run build` (or the command you use to build your assets) and before you do the native build.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for your help @jcesarmobile & @FrankM,

I have solved the issue.

On DevOps, issues occurred because of the old version of ionic & with an android folder on it. Updated the ionic & capacitor version and build currently, I have deployed to Play Store via DevOps.

Things Done in Steps:

1. Remove Existing Android Folder from Source.
2. Update Capacitor & Ionic Version.
3. Add Android Platform and Sync.
4. Build on Android Studio.
5. Run CI/CD Pipeline on DevOps.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same issue. In my case, running "npx cap sync" solved my problem.

Comment: That was already an answer roughly 2 years ago.